# pointers are bi directional iterators?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I have stumbled upon something that has me utterly confused.

`std::reverse()` takes bidirectional iterators as arguments into the function, but when I pass pointers to the function, it seems to work fine and actually reverse the string.

```
void reverseFour(char* str) {
    reverse(str, str + strlen(str));
}

int main {
    char *str = "hello";
    str += '/0';
    reverseFour(str);
}
```

So, my question is, how is this possible? Bidirectional iterators are not pointers, right?

Comment: no but pointers are bidirectional iterators, the iterator interface was chosen to be compatible with pointer syntax

Comment: cows are animals does not mean animals are cows.

Comment: Pointers are even random access iterators, at least when they point to elements of an array.

Comment: @nwp -- and any pointer that you're using as an iterator has to point into an array. If it doesn't, you can't increment it or decrement it.

Comment: And pointers can also be contiguos iterators (C++17)

Comment: If you want to show the code works fine, at least you need to post valid code. Your code has too many errors.

Comment: The code shown has **undefined behavior**, because `main()` is passing a pointer to a string literal  to `std::reverse()` (and a non-const pointer at that, which is not allowed in C++11, unless you tell the compiler to disable that restriction). `reverse()` will try to write to read-only memory, which will likely crash the app. To make the code valid, use `char str[] = "hello";` instead.

Answer (score 7):

A pointer is, in fact, a kind of [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). This is even better than a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), in that any algorithm that requires a `BidirectionalIterator` will also accept a `RandomAccessIterator`, including pointers.

This is quite deliberate, and very useful.

There does, of course, exist other kinds of iterators, particularly some types that are dedicated to being just iterators and nothing more (you'll get these from `std::set` and `std::map`, for example). But the concept of an [`Iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) is something that C++ deliberately keeps rather general.

Comment: How one category of iterators could be better than another?

Comment: @Slava: Because you can do more things with them, without any penalty.

Comment: Then integers are even better and we should stop using any iterators

Comment: @Slava: Integers are not a kind of iterator. Stop being silly.

Comment: That does not stop for them to be better.

Comment: @Slava: Better _iterators_. You're moving the goalposts. Your first comment talks about comparing categories of iterators. Now you're talking about who knows what.

Comment: @Slava `int` doesn't fulfill the requirements of any iterator category.

Comment: Iterator category does not fullfill requirements to be better or worse.

Comment: @Slava: Well we'll just agree to disagree on that okay.

Comment: You are giving wrong impression, if `std::vector` provides better iterator then it is better container than `std::map` for example, which is simply wrong.

Comment: @Slava: Now you're posing a strawman argument, for that is not at all what I said.

Comment: Thanks @Remy, looks nice. "There do" was correct, though; "kinds" is plural.

Comment: @Slava `std::vector`'s iterators are objectively more convenient and powerful than `std::map`'s iterators, though that doesn't imply that `std::vector`  is always superior to `std::map`. Only that it is so with regards to the type of iterators they provide.

Comment: @Slava A random access iterator is better in the sense that you can do more operations with it (it is less restrictive).

Comment: @NathanOliver is raw pointer better than iterator?

Comment: Since a pointer and an iterator can be the same thing I would say no.  An iterator does allow you to have more stuff though but `iterator_traits` supplants the typedef's so it's kind of moot.

Comment: I'm better than continuing this silly discussion, I know that much.

Comment: @NathanOliver But I do not follow, one side you say less restrictive is better, then you say it is restricted by `iterator_traits` and it is better than pointer. Can you make your mind? I do not follow your logic. Raw pointer is less restrictive than iterator so it is better right?

Comment: @Slava `iterator_triats` allows pointers to have the same typedef's that iterators have so an iterator doesn't really have an advantage about the typedefs is what said.  A raw pointer and a random access iterator is basically the exact same thing.  And with that I'm done.

Comment: @NathanOliver right you cannot prove your point but you have to support, so you are done. Nice